# Is ohms low violated here?

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance, voltage

As per power equation $P=V×I$, voltage is inversely proportional to current as power of load remains constant. So why we get greater output from electrical loads with increase in voltage. (whether it may be resisitive or inductive)?

Comment: Are you keeping the power constant in the scenario of "why we get greater output from electrical loads with increase in voltage"?

Comment: Re, "...as power of load remains constant..." There are not many simple devices that will draw constant power regardless of the supplied voltage. What device did you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

> As per power equation P=V×I, voltage is inversely proportional to
>   current as power of load

*If* constant power is delivered to a load then, as you write, the current through the load is inversely proportional to the voltage across the load.

But, for a resistive load of fixed resistance $R_L$, the voltage across (current through) must be constant if the power delivered to the load is constant.

Recall that, for a resistor, the associated power can be expressed as a function of just the voltage across or of just the current through:

$$P_R = \frac{V_R^2}{R} = I_R^2\cdot R$$

and so, *if* the power delivered to a fixed resistive load is constant, it follows that both the voltage across and current through are constant.

> So why we get greater output from electrical loads with increase in
>   voltage.

If the voltage across a fixed resistive load increases, the power increases - there's no way around that.  You can't, without contradiction, stipulate that the power is constant but the voltage across isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The question suggests to me that you have been confusing yourself.

Usually, when you increase the voltage to a load, the current will increase accordingly. The result is that the power delivered (which, as you stated, is $P=V\cdot I$), will increase.

You cannot simply say "now I pretend the power is constant, and I increase the voltage, so why isn't the power constant?". You would have to ask yourself "what happens to the current?". And of course, if the construction of the load doesn't change, then increasing the voltage will increase the current. That's Ohm's law.

The only "violation" that occurs is in your initial statement, where you posit that power will be constant. Starting from a false premise you end up in a confusing pickle.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no violation of ohms law if we write:

(1)  $V=P/I$

All this says is that in order for $P$ to be constant if voltage is increased than current must be decreased. E.g., if we double the voltage we need to halve the current for $P$ to be the same.

Per Ohms Law:

(2)  $V=IR$

Plugging  value of $V$ from (2) into (1):

$IR=P/I$

$P=I^2R$

Comment: The question was "Is Ohms Law Violated Here". Presumable "Here" refers to V and I being inversely related if P is constant. That's the question I answered.

Comment: And, by the way, I answered the question minutes after it was posted and before the chair edited it. In the original question equation (1) of my response was in the question. It's been edited out. That raises a point. How do folks know what question we are answering if it is subsequently edited?